# python: ssh connection

Tags: python, bash, file-upload, upload, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the simplest way to SSH using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python)

I want to use a python script to connect via ssh to my server, upload a file and after that do bash commands like "pwd".
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python

Comment: Other than learning some python what are you trying to do that you need python for? All of this could be a single bash shell script.