# Secure communication between servers

Tags: python, encryption

I'm writing a simple control panel. It's going to be hosted on a single server, which communicates with other servers to do whatever it needs to. I need suggestions on how to do this securely, both from an authentication and an encryption standpoint. The only thing I've come up with so far is to use RSA keys to encrypt data on the master server and decrypt it on the slave, which would accomplish what I need but something seems flawed about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

See also: [What is the simplest way to SSH using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python)

Comment: And it's more useful to use sshfs then FTP for file transefering. Author wrote about control panel for server :)

Comment: This seems to me like the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Stunnel](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/stunnel-universal-ssl-tunnel-for-network-daemons.html) is pretty handy. I like it since the code doesn't need to deal with encryption at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSL with client/server certificate validation.

[Validate SSL certificates with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

We are developing [Versile Python](https://versile.com/products/vpy/), if you need object-level interaction [with python objects](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/recipes/native.html) over a secure channel you may want to have a look. You can use TLS or VTS to negotiate secure connections using RSA keys, or you can connect [over SSH](https://versile.com/doc/vpy/current/recipes/pipe.html).

Other python object interaction frameworks you may want to consider are Pyro and RPyC.