# Zip files in FTP using Python

Tags: python, ftp

I've been trying to write a python code which can archive the files of ftp server into one zip file and download it :

And so far I understand I need to use ftplib for this:

```
import os
from time import strftime
from ftplib import FTP

day = strftime("%d")
today = strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

link = FTP(ftphost)
link.login(passwd = ftp_pass, user = ftp_user)
link.cwd(file_path)
```

And I think I need to use `FTP.sendcmd` function to send a command to FTP server to have it archive all the files into one and actually I am not really sure which command I need to send though.

To download the file, the function seems legit to me:

```
import os
def download(ftp,file, localdir):
    f = open(os.path.join(localdir, file),"wb")
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + file,f.write)
    f.close()
```

Can someone put together what I've been trying to do here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've found the solution I believe.

I need to use SSH (Secure Shell) or sFTP I think they mean same thing. There is a lib called [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) and it offers sending commands, connection, etc. for SSH. It seems using ftplib won't help since you cannot run Shell Commands via ftplib. You need a secure connection to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the FTP protocol does not provide for running arbitrary client-specified commands on the server. See for yourself: [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959).

Even if it did, it would be a major security concern (with public FTP servers at least).

Comment: That's a possibility, provided you have `ssh` access to the server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python