# SSH a linux box using subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, fabric, paramiko, pexpect

I have a requirement where i need to do the following

I need to ssh to a linux box , run a command , get the output back and i need to do some manipulations.

Is that possible via python subprocess module.

Basically i need a .py code in which i will give the ip address, username and password for connecting to the linux box and run a command and get the output.

Also is that possible via any other modules available in Python.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: please do some research before posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python

Comment: If you need to give a password, I don't think you can do that via subprocess.

Comment: Have you considered using [a proper Python SSH module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is tagged with "paramiko", so why don't you just use that?

> I need to ssh to a linux box , run a command , get the output back and
>   i need to do some manipulations.

**ssh to a linux box (or any other ssh server):**

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.load_system_host_keys()
>>> ssh.connect(hostname='localhost', username='haiprasan86', password='secret')
>>> print ssh
<paramiko.SSHClient object at 0xdf2590>
```

**run a command:**

```
>>> _, out, err = ssh.exec_command('ls -l /etc/passwd')
>>> # block until remote command completes
>>> status = out.channel.recv_exit_status()
>>> print status
0
```

**get the output back:**

```
>>> print out.readlines()
['-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2351 Mar 27 10:57 /etc/passwd\n']
```

I don't know what manipulations you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one command, you can simply append it to the command line:

```
ssh user@host "echo foo"
```

would then return foo. If you use `ssh-agent` with your public key in the remote host's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`-file then you don't even need to ask for the password.

Answer (score 0):

Other options would be [fabric](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/) or if you need to interact with the remote command, [fexpect](http://ilogue.com/jasper/blog/fexpect--dealing-with-prompts-in-fabric-with-pexpect/).