# Any way to execute commands on a remote ssh client from python?

Tags: python, ssh

I wonder if we have a way of enabling the following this:
Python script running on **Machine1**

**Machine1** -------pass sudo commands, ssh password, sudo password------> **Machine2**
**Machine1** <--------Get output and store in python variable--------- **Machine2**

Can we do this without using paramiko?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perform commands over ssh with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python)

Comment: `paramiko` is the way. What's wrong with it? From the python docs: "Paramiko is a native Python implementation of SSH. "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to SSH using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233655/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-ssh-using-python)

Comment: this might be possible using subprocess.Popen with piping stdout and stdin, and processing stdout in real-time, without using `.communicate()`. But if want actually do that thing: WAT ?